# Laravel passport GuzzleHttp error API not data

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I use GuzzleHtpp and passport to make login page by `vue.js` and I got the problem in Insomnia API in this API URL: http://ledger.work/api/login

this my AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login (Request $request)
    {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        try {
            $response = $http->post('http://ledger.work/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => 2,
                    'client_secret' => 'f7peunlDCOgUK1qEK0HP4267wtlb6zTkjxLshvBj',
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                ]
            ]);
            return $response->getBody();
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
            } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }


    }
}
```

and this is my Route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');

Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index');
```

[Its just loading and got no thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVJPr.png)

Insomnia API just loading and got nothing and solution.

Comment: hi. did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because guzzle isn't work with `php artisan serve`. Use xampp under local domain or something like this (XAMPP).